# Read data from excel after a string matches

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I want to read the entire row data and store it in variables, later use them in selenium to write it to webelements. Programming language is Python.

Example: I have an excel sheet of Incidents and their details regarding priority, date, assignee etc

If I give the string as INC00000 it should match the excel data, fetch all the above details and store it in separate variables like

```
INC #= INC0000 Priority= Moderate Date = 11/2/2020
```

Is this feasible? I tried and failed writing a code. Please suggest other possible ways to do this.

Comment: Please share the code you tried. what library are you trying to use?

Comment: i figured it out after i posted my question on SO. its serving my purpose now.

Answer (score 0):

I would,

1. load the sheet into a pandas DataFrame
2. filter the corresponding column in the DataFrame by the INC # of interest
3. convert the row to dictionary (assuming the INC filter produces only 1 row)
4. get the corresponding value in the dictionary to assign to the corresponding webelement

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("full_file_path", sheet_name="name_of_sheet")
dict_data = df[df['INC #']].to_dict("record")  #  <-- assuming the "INC #" are in column named "INC #" in the spreadsheet
webelement1.send_keys(dict_data[columnname1])
webelement2.send_keys(dict_data[columnname2])
webelement3.send_keys(dict_data[columnname3])
.
. 
.
```

Comment: its throwing a key error : out of index. column name is "Number" that has the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code and do the changes as per your variables after saving your excel file as csv:
[Please find the dummy data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUkMv.png)

```
import csv

# Set up input and output variables for the script
gTrack = open("file1.csv", "r")

# Set up CSV reader and process the header
csvReader = csv.reader(gTrack)
header = csvReader.next()
print header
id_index = header.index("id")
date_index = header.index("date ")
var1_index = header.index("var1")
var2_index = header.index("var2")

# # Make an empty list
cList = []

 # Loop through the lines in the file and get required id
for row in csvReader:
    id = row[id_index]
    if(id == 'INC001') :
     date  = row[date_index]
     var1 =  row[var1_index]
     var2 = row[var2_index]
     cList.append([id,date,var1,var2])

# # Print the coordinate list
print cList
```